# I have a problem with the button position in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making an app in Android Studio, my problem is the position on the button. In the layout the position is correct, but in the simulator the button is in the left corner.

Example:

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb31g.png)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZjjk.png)

My code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F10000"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="INICIO"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="622dp />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `tools` keyword in your Button is just to show in layout and nothing more, for define the position of the button you should rely on your button parent,for example if its `LinearLayout` you can change the position of button by giving it `android:layout_gravity`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F10000"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="INICIO"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```